# ROW_NUMBER and Grouping of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data that looks like this:
[image: table1]

What I want is to have a row number that is group by GroupCode,Group Description,SubGroup and subgroup class and I want to retain the ordering by account code that will look like this:
[image: table2]

What's the proper way of seting a row number at the same time grouping them?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by GroupCode, GroupDescription, SubGroup)
. . .
```

However, this doesn't guarantee the ordering by `accountCode`.  That will require more work.  First, determine the minimum account code for each grouping, then use `dense_rank()` on that:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by minac)
from (select t.*,
             min(accountCode) over (partition by GroupCode, GroupDescription, SubGroup) as minac
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `DENSE_RANK` window function:

```
SELECT
    rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY GroupCode, GroupDescription, SubgroupClass),
    *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY rn, AccountCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you need this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT groupcode, 
                groupdescription, 
                subgroup, 
                subgroupclass, 
                Min(accountcode) AS accountcode 
         FROM   your_table 
         GROUP  BY groupcode, 
                   groupdescription, 
                   subgroup, 
                   subgroupclass), 
     ordr 
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY accountcode) AS RN, 
                * 
         FROM   cte) 
SELECT C.rn, 
       A.* 
FROM   your_table A 
       INNER JOIN cte C 
               ON A.groupcode = C.groupcode 
                  AND A.groupdescription = C.groupdescription 
                  AND A.subgroup = C.subgroup 
                  AND A.subgroupclass = C.subgroupclass
```